# Anime where a tiny woman swims in a cup of water

Tags: story-identification, anime

Trying to find the anime with a very tiny anime girl. She has long black hair and she is put into a normal sized water cup by a normal sized guy. Then after swimming he removed her and she bites his finger. Then he feeds her something I think?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: I saw it on YouTube 11 years ago. It came across it on Facebook last year but forgot to save the name of it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Are you sure about the black hair? If the hair was red, this could be "Ponyo".

Comment: Definitely not Ponyo. She is similar to squid girl in size and what she eats. Literally all I remember about her is the details I have

Comment: There were several versions of Thumbelina, and this sounds like one of them.